# adding textInput values to another text input using js function in Yii 2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii, yii2

Simply I'm trying to add value of text Input fields to another as : http://jsfiddle.net/MaK2k/1/

my form code :

```
    <?php
        $script = <<< JS
            $('#amount_value_id').keyup(function(){
                var amountSum=0;
                $('#amount_value_id').each(function(){
                    if (this.value != "")
                        amountSum+=parseInt(this.value);
                });
                // alert('foo');
                $("#totalamount").text(amountSum);
                //console.log(amountSum);

            });
        JS;
        $this->registerJs($script);
    ?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(["id" => "project-form"]); ?>

  <?php foreach ($project as $i => $project) { ?>

     <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3" id="amount_value_id">
                                    <?= $form->field($project, "[{$i}]amount")->textInput(); ?>
                                </div>

                                  <?php } ?>

                                    <div class="col-lg-2" id="totalamount">
            <?php echo $form->field($model, 'total_amount')->textInput(['maxlength' => 128, 'id' => 'totalamount']) ?>
        </div>
```

In the text Input for total amount that should holds the total sum is giving NaN !! .What I'm doing ??

Comment: Accept numbers only and reject all non-numeric inputs or exclude all non-numeric inputs, as you please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your jsfiddle. When you enter **numeric value** everything is right, but when you enter text value, it gives "NaN". It's obvious, because you are using `parseInt()`. When you enter a text like "test" in the input field, your code tries to convert "text" string into integer value and so the result is NaN. A workaround for this problem is to preventing user from entering non-numeric value. Another solution is using [javascript `isNaN()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) function. `isNaN()` checks for `illegal` numbers value.

Comment: you right i used $.isNumeric() and it works .thanks alot